# How much health does a Health potion restore?

Tags: candy-box

In Candy Box, how many hit points does using a Health Potion give you? Are there multiple different types of Health Potion available later on or do they scale with the number of hit points you have in total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Health Potion restores 50 HP.

Once you have the Cauldron, you can craft Major Health Potions that restore 100 HP.